# Need dataset of english letters

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, language, images

I have done one assignment of classifying digits using Back propagation Neural Network. Now I want to test it on english letters.

Can anybody tell me from where can I get the dataset of English letters (letters of size 20 * 20 pixels would be more helpful). If possible then please provide dataset of letters of any other language also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these datasets:

http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/UJI+Pen+Characters

Comment: I need grayscale images of only small letters or capital letters separated. My BPNN is not strong enough to recognize 'a' and 'A' as same entity.